# Как сделать функцию внутри инлайн кнопки?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

подскажите, пожалуйста, как внедрить в инлайн кнопку функцию?

Под приветственным сообщением есть одна кнопка, которая должна отвечать за функционал и активировать всю последующую работу бота.

**Вот кусок с несоединенными частями:**

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Заполнить объявление', callback_data='question_1')
    markup.add(item)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """\
   Добро пожаловать!
   Здесь вы можете заполнить форму для публикации вашего объявления
   """, reply_markup=markup)

 @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
 def callback_inline(call):
     if call.data == 'question_1':

 def first_step(message):
     msg = bot.reply_to(message, """\
    Ответьте, пожалуйста, на следующие вопросы:

    Шаг 1. Перечислите через запятую (без #) тематики вашей площадки. 
    """)
     bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_second_step)
```

И далее идет куча этих step'ов с последующей обработкой

А как соединить это все с кнопкой я не понимаю..

Comment: Наблюдаю на стеке повальное засилье ботов под телеграмм, новомодный тренд? Почитайте про конечный автомат, может станет понятней как делаются такие штуки, ну или упрощенный вариант - машина состояний

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, интересно, что имея профильное образование, и плотно использовав конечные автоматы (Final State Machine)  в своей практике, я никогда не слышал о машине состояний - (State Mаchine). Она реально используется?

Comment: @Сергей Это упрощенная версия конечного автомата. Почему она не должна использоваться? Самое простое что приходит на ум - вы находитесь в игре(1), на экране меню(2), или в финальных титрах(3) - вот вам машина состояний

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, просто не разу не встречал. Персептрон - упрощённая версия нейронной сети, но он же не используется.

Comment: @Сергей нейронки не мое, не могу ничего сказать про использование там :) но для обучения и в кодах джунов и мидов - машину состояний можно встретить часто, только зачастую они сами этого не знают :) кстати switch case - это машина состояний :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, ясно, спасибо. Значит, и я её использую - скоро смогу стать джуном или мидлом тогда:-)